# Duplicate of "duplicate" flagging option?

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

So why are there *two* options to close a post for the same reason?

Option 1 (main page):

[image: main flag dialog]

Option 2 (under "it should be closed..."):

[image: should be closed flag dialog][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcsb1.png)

Comment: The reason is the 2nd page is the close vote dialog.  The duplicate link needs to appear there for close voters.  The first page is the flag dialog.  I believe it is because SE want to encourage closing as duplicates as the first option, so they felt giving it a special place in the flag dialog would do that.

Comment: as a 3K user, I can flag a post for specific reasons that will go to a moderator or into the low quality review queue.  But I can't flag a post as a duplicate or unclear or anything else in that 2nd dialog.  If I tried that, my flag would automatically be converted to a close vote.  Since you don't have 3K rep yet, all of your actions in both of those dialogs are consider flags, the only difference between them is who reviews and handles the flag.

Comment: But why do two different entities need to handle duplicates and achieve the same effect in the end?

Comment: It is a tad confusing, adding to the confusing names already there. Probs why many people don't bother raising flags and think it's for seasoned users. (Gripe? Sure, I think they should all be renamed with some amalgamated)

Comment: @psubsee2003 so, which one should I chose?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it exists in 2 places is because of the dialogs themselves.

For Option 2, that is actually the same dialog that is used for 3K users to cast close votes.  When you select a flag under "should be closed...", you are actually give the same options as users who can vote to close.  So the duplicate link exists here because it is an option is the close vote dialog.

For Option 1, this is effective a shortcut to the duplicate vote dialog.  The SO community team want to encourage duplicate flagging over all other close flags, so they gave it special prominence on the main flag dialog, rather than burying it in the close dialog. But there probably was not enough of a reason to remove it from the "should be closed" dialog, although it does seems to be confusing if you don't know that both options do the same thing.

So, to wrap up, it doesn't matter which one you pick.  Both go to **exactly** the same place and do **exactly** the same thing.

Comment: I'm fairly new here, so this is a newbie's opinion.
If both options actually do the same, then why show both? You could detect if a users comes from dialog 1, and then hide the option in dialog 2. If a 3K user is casting a close vote, they go directly to dialog 2 I reckon, so then the option to mark as duplicate should be shown. It's basic user experience design.

**In short: show the option 1 time, depending on whether the user comes from dialog 1 or not.**