# Make it easier to flag a duplicate

Tags: discussion, flags

I currently have low rep. I discover dupe questions all the time - I go to answer, and with one single google search, I have the answer, and it is usualy also on stackoverflow.

If I flag, there is no direct "this is a duplicate" option - also I have only 10 flags allowed.

The flag would of course be reviewed by higher ranking members.

In the interest of keeping SO clean, wouldn't it make sense to open up uplicate reporting? i.e add a specific "This is a duplicate" option in the dialog, and have it not chew up flag points.

Comment: There's _two_ "flag as duplicate" options (see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255511/). Are you sure you're not getting them?

Comment: @JoshCaswell He can't see it because he doesn't have 50 rep yet (for the duplicate comment).

Comment: Gain enough reputation on a particular tag, and you'll get mjölnir at hand. Otherwise you're restricted to provide appropriate comments, flags and community close votes.

Comment: I don't believe that casting a flag generates that comment, @mmking.

Comment: @JoshCaswell As a user who has not yet unlocked close vote privileges, I'm fairly certain that the "Possible duplicate of" comment is generated when flagged as duplicate. And I'm pretty sure that you [need 50 rep to flag as duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118124/where-on-earth-is-the-mark-duplicate-ui-on-stack-overflow/217233#217233).

Comment: I stand corrected, @mmking; thanks for the link.

Comment: Yes, no. Im not talking about marking it straight up. I just thought more freedom to report would be nice.

Comment: In theory, as a currently-low rep user, I should be inclined to copy paste the answer for the rep - a very quick and easy 25 points!

Maybe rep should be given for flagging of duplicates that turn out to be correct?

Comment: @Patrick clearly you're here to do the right thing, so you're not going to scum the system like that ;) There are already enough deadbeats who harvest the easy dupe-google rewards, just have a little patience until you find your moment of glory with a proper answer to a proper question.

Answer (score 4):

You get "flag as duplicate" at 50 rep points, I don't expect this to be relaxed any time soon. You also need 50 rep points to comment - so there is not much left except to just get to 50 points.

When you get to 50 - flag as duplicate as soon as you found one. This will save time to everyone - whoever tries to reply (to hopefully skip the post) and whoever have Vote To Close (with or without gold mjölnir).

Copying content from other question would be plagiarism (without attribution) or just duplication and will likely get well deserved discussion with moderators - don't do that.

Comment: No comment can be made below 50 rep either - only option is to answer with a link to the dupe, or use flag function "in need of moderator attention"

Copying content - lol ok thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Patrick - always forgetting that you need 50 to comment on other posts too... Removing that part.

Comment: This is interesting - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251913/4919054

Solution: divorce duplicate-marking from closing, provide rewards for solving someone's problem by pointing to an existing question.